# RobotFramework - Connecting to SQL SERVER integrated windows logon

Tags: sql-server, connection, robotframework, trusted

I was trying to connect to the SQL Server 2012 database using the robot framework
for a long time unsuccessfully, finally came up with this

### *** Settings ***

```
Test Setup   Connect To Database Using Custom Params 
   pymssql     ${server},${username},${password},${databasename},${trusted}
```

all in a single line with tab spaces inbetween

**Where**
Test Setup - Is the key word used under Settings for setting up the DB Environment in this case
Connect To Database Using Custom Params  -- are the keywords to connect to database which are found in the databaselibrary of RobotFramework
pymssql - Module for connecting with SQLSERVER database

The below are the parameters to be passed

1. server - name of the server in single quote
2. username - Username along with the domain name - format - 'domain-name\username'
3. Password - self explanatory
4. Trusted - The value should be set as 'True'

This helped me in establishing the connection with sql server 2012, but i still face issues.

> **Error message**  Setup failed: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (, line 1)

Comment: Is that exactly how your code looks? because you cant use commas... Use at least 2 spaces...

Comment: Yes, this is how my code looks, No the comma's are part of the input format provided to pymssql

Comment: yeah dont do that, remove the commas and replace it with 2 spaces instead - RF doesnt understand what commas are like a normal programming lang. Instead it uses two spaces. So replace those commas with 2 spaces and see what happens

Comment: Will try it now

Comment: Still failing ! :(

Comment: Can you edit your question with the new current code youre using please?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I was looking for the answer to the same problem and worked out that it should be the following

```
Test Setup   Connect To Database Using Custom Params 
   pymssql     '${server}','${username}','${password}','${databasename}','${trusted}'
```

pymsql requires the commas between the variables to identify each separate part.  RF passes the whole thing a one long string to pymssql by putting the ' around each variable it is clearly identified as a separate connection setting by pymssql.

This worked for me when I wanted to connect to a server and run queries on several different databases at the same time

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    pymssql    '${server}','${username}','${password}'
```

I can then use the database name in the query or execution string

Answer (score 0):

In Robotframework if you want to work with SQL Server. Down load pyodbc package. Add Library to the testcase. Then write query to execute.
Below is the sample code

*** Settings ***
Library DatabaseLibrary
Library OperatingSystem
Library pyodbc